# Outlook 2013 customization and integration in exchange online

Tags: vsto, exchange-server, office365, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

I want to customize the appointment window used in Outlook. I want add few custom fields. I am using VSTO (VS2013) to develop this addin.

So far I have added a button in ribbon of appointment tab. On click of which I am opening a new form with custom fields. Now when user completes the form and other appointment details and appointment is saved then along with all appointment data, custom data entered by user should also get emailed to recipients.
And also that custom data would be stored in Exchange, and later that data can be queries to generate report.

So my question is - how do override the save appointment event so that I can add additional data in appointment and also how do I save it to exchange online using office 365.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using an Exchange account which is the case with Office 365. The `UserProperties` of an Outlook item is kept in Exchange.

You can persist the custom data in [UserProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn352411.aspx)

If you want to Save your custom data when the appoitment is saved. You should put an event handler in the `AfterWrite` event. See AppointmentItem event [list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.appointmentitem_events(v=office.14).aspx).

Comment: Thank you @Benoit, I will try this and let you know.

Comment: @devson how did you  manage to save your UserProperties. Each time when I restart outlook my UserProperties are gone.

Comment: @user668338 - it was done long back, unable to recall now.